# read .Xmodmap on login in Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon, xmodmap

I am running Linux Mint 17 and want Cinnamon to read from my `.Xmodmap` on start.

Seems that `~/.Xmodmap` is not being read by default.

How do I do that?